# Less program rendering breaks

Tags: terminal, less, rendering

I've been experiencing this problem on multiple computers, over a long time, but I could never find any mention of it anywhere so I thought I should ask it to understand whether it's only me once and for all.

The `less` program, used to view and paginate long text, often breaks its terminal rendering when scrolling. This also happens in programs that do similar things, such as `git diff` (not sure whether it internally uses `less` or not).

Some parts of the text disappear when scrolling, or get overwritten by something else.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Any writes to `stderr` from programs running in in the terminal will corrupt the `less` display, but a Page Down and Page Up will usually correct this. It most commonly occurs when piping to `less` in order to scroll output from a program which generates error messages as well as normal output. If this is your case, you can pipe both `stderr` and `stdout` with `2>&1 |` (or `|&` in `bash`); or you can redirect `stderr` to a file (or `2>/dev/null` if you want to suppress it completely). Note that if `stderr` are intermixed, buffering means that they may interrupt each other mid-line.

Comment: This could have been, but the particular instance that prompted me to write this was a simple `make |& less`, so I'm not sure whether this applies..

Comment: In `make` not only may you get error messages from `make` itself, but also from any number of programs it may schedule according to the rules in `Makefile`. With `|&` standard output and error messages will be randomly intermixed, but [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378) shows you how to enable line-buffering for a command, which should make the intermixed output a lot more legible.